# How can i detect what code base a function is running in with no references to classes?

Tags: java

I am making an application which works with a game that runs in an applet (i didn't make the game, i am just making things for it, in this case, the launcher), but the applet is not coded very neatly so it has calls to `System.exit(int)`.

I need the launcher to stay open on the event of the game crashing or the user clicking the quit game button and *attempting* to call `System.exit(int)` so the only way i can do this is by making a `SecurityManager` that functions like `System.exit(int)` go to check with it to see if it's allowed to exit the Java VM, if it's not, it will throw an exeption.

The second part of the solution for keeping the launcher open is by creating an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` so it can ignore the exception thrown by trying to exit; By implementing this, i can also have the launcher notify the user of a bug in the launcher when it's not the exiting exception (if it's something else, that's not supposed to be there so it'll result in a bug report).

Now, the actual problem that this question is about is **how can i make the `SecurityManager` aware of if the game or my launcher that is trying to call `System.exit(int)`?** I still need my launcher to be able to exit when it wants to, the game is just what i want to restrict.

---

Someone suggested using `ProtectionDomain` to detect what code base is running the code but i don't understand how this is implementable. You don't have references to classes in the `SecurityManager`.

Comment: Sounds like you want a separate `ProtectionDomain` (and `CodeSource`) for the classes that make up the applet.

Comment: I tried looking into this and couldn't figure out how to implement this, could you give a little more detail?